# hashtable keys() keySet() which is better

Tags: hashtable

Just curiously I am asking which is the better method to use Hashtable.keys() or Hashtable.keySet(). Any one would have been sufficient. Why have they given 2 methods with different return types. Is there any performance drawback/benefit of one over the other ?

Answer (score 0):

keySet is there because

it returns a Set view of the keys contained in this Hashtable. The Set is backed by the Hashtable, so changes to the Hashtable are reflected in the Set, and vice-versa. The Set supports element removal (which removes the corresponding entry from the Hashtable), but not element addition.

And keys just returns an enumeration of the keys in this hashtable, no changes will be reflected after getting enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the funcitonal difference mentioned by Rahul, Hashtable itself is an old artifact of earlier java version and retrofitted to implement Map interface.
So keySet is a later construct required by the Map interface.

Additionally, if this is new code that you are writing, you should read up the api details for this data structure on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html and see if you should consider the guideline and use HashMap or other later Collections instead.